# How do you trade artifacts between heroes?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I have two heroes in *Might and Magic: Heroes VI*.  Each has an artifact that is part of a set.  I would like to trade this artifact from one hero to the other. Both heroes are in the same town. I can't figure out how to transfer the artifact from one hero to the other. What do you have to click on to make this happen, if it is even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can actually trade artifacts in town.  But if you move one hero slightly out of town, then switch to the other one and click on the hero that just left, you should get an icon of two hands shaking.  When your hero reaches the other, you will get a screen that will allow them to trade units and items.

Comment: Hooray, it worked.